# Rename Participant add file extension automatically if it was removed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring, eclipse-rcp

I created a `RenamePartipant` that reacts only when changes are made to a certain file in the project workspace.

If the user removes the file extension with the rename resource dialog, then I want to add the extension to the new name automatically.

However I am a bit stuck about how to achieve this. I can get what the new file name the user has placed with `getArguments().getNewName()`, but how do I add the extension string and reset the name?

Comment: I don't think you can - that would mess up all the other rename participants

Comment: Is there any way to discourage/stop the user from removing the extension? For example, in the rename resource dialog selection highlight only the file name part without extension when the dialog opens instead of having the selection over the whole file name as it is now by default.